# Google web push notification display on desktop time

Tags: web-push

I did web push notification with google firebase sevice on my site.
It is work, everything is cool but when I receive a push notification so if i dont click on it its disappears itself in 20 seconds. Is it possible to make notification dont disappears so fast?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `requireInteraction` to `true`when you call [showNotification()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification).

Comment: thanks but where i can implement it?

in firebase-messaging-sw.js? how?

// firebase-messaging-sw.js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxx'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();